# Heston stochastic volatility, Girsanov theorem

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingale, girsanov

How can we apply Girsanov's theorem to a stochastic volatility model?
In Heston's model the dynamics are given by
\begin{align*} 
dS_t &= \mu S_t dt + \sqrt{v_t}S_t  d\widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_{1,t}, \\
dv_t &= \kappa ( \theta - v_t)  dt + \sigma \sqrt{v_t}  \left( \rho d \widehat{W}_{1,t}^\mathbb{P} +\sqrt{1- \rho^2} d\widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_{2,t} \right) 
\end{align*}
where $\widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_{1,t}$ and $\widehat{W}_{2,t}^\mathbb{P}$ are the independent standard Brownian motions, and $\rho \in (-1,1)$ the correlation coefficient.
Using Girsanov's theorem we would have for the stock process
$$\widehat{W}^\mathbb{Q}_{1,t} = \left(\widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_{1,t} + \frac{\mu - r}{\sqrt{v_t}}t\right).$$
Can we also apply Girsanov's theorem for the variance SDE? More precisely, what happens with $d\widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_{2,t}$. In some textbooks they write
$d\widehat{W}^\mathbb{Q}_{2,t} = \left(d\widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_{2,t} + \lambda dt\right). $
But then we have
\begin{align*}
dv_t &= \kappa ( \theta - v_t)  dt + \sigma \sqrt{v_t}  \left( \rho d \widehat{W}_{1,t}^\mathbb{P} +\sqrt{1- \rho^2} d\widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_{2,t} \right) \\
&= \kappa ( \theta - v_t)  dt + \sigma \sqrt{v_t}  \left( 
\rho \left( d \widehat{W}_{1,t}^{\mathbb{Q}_\lambda} - \frac{\mu - r}{\sqrt{v_t}} dt  \right)
+\sqrt{1- \rho^2} \left( d \widehat{W}^\mathbb{Q}_{2,t} - \lambda d t)
\right) \right) \\
&= \kappa \left( \theta - \frac{\rho}{\kappa} \sigma (\mu - r) - v_t
- \frac{\sqrt{1- \rho^2 } }{\kappa} \lambda \sigma \sqrt{v_t} \right) dt + \sigma \sqrt{v_t} \left( \rho d\widehat{W}^\mathbb{Q}_{1,t} + \sqrt{1- \rho^2} d \widehat{W}^\mathbb{Q}_{2,t} \right)
\end{align*}
It's strange that I never saw it that way. Can anyone give me a clue?

Answer (score 12):

Consider the Heston (1993) model under the **real world measure** ($\mathbb{P}$)
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}S_t&=\mu^\mathbb{P} S_t\mathrm{d}t+\sqrt{v_t}S_t\mathrm{d}B_{S,t}^\mathbb{P}, \\
\mathrm{d}v_t&=\kappa^\mathbb{P} (\bar{v}^\mathbb{P}-v_t)\mathrm{d}t+\sigma^\mathbb{P}\sqrt{v_t}\mathrm{d}B_{v,t}^\mathbb{P},
\end{align*}
where $\mathrm{d}B_{S,t}^\mathbb{P}\mathrm{d}B_{v,t}^\mathbb{P}=\rho^\mathbb{P}\mathrm{d}t$.

---

I define the **market prices of risk** (or ``Girsanov kernel'') to be
\begin{align}
\varphi_S &= \frac{(\mu^\mathbb{P}-r)S_t}{\sqrt{v_t}S_t}=\frac{\mu^\mathbb{P}-r}{\sqrt{v_t}}, \\
\varphi_v &= \frac{\lambda v_t}{\sigma^\mathbb{P}\sqrt{v_t}}=\frac{\lambda}{\sigma^\mathbb{P}}\sqrt{v_t},
\end{align}
where $\lambda$ is a parameter.

---

The **two-dimensional Girsanov Theorem** gives rise to
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}}\bigg|_{\mathcal{F}_t}= \exp\bigg(&-\int_0^t \frac{\mu^\mathbb{P}-r}{\sqrt{v_s}}\mathrm{d}B_{S,s}^\mathbb{P} -\int_0^t \frac{\lambda\sqrt{v_s}}{\sigma^\mathbb{P}}\mathrm{d}B_{v,s}^\mathbb{P} \\
&+ \int_0^t \frac{ (\mu^\mathbb{P}-r)\lambda\rho^\mathbb{P}}{\sigma^\mathbb{P}}\mathrm{d}s-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \left(\frac{(\mu^\mathbb{P}-r)^2}{v_s}+\frac{\lambda^2v_s}{(\sigma^\mathbb{P})^2} \right)\mathrm{d}s\bigg),
\end{align*}
such that
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}W_{S,t}^\mathbb{Q} &= \mathrm{d}B_{S,t}^\mathbb{P} + \varphi_S\mathrm{d}t, \\
\mathrm{d}W_{v,t}^\mathbb{Q} &= \mathrm{d}B_{v,t}^\mathbb{P} + \varphi_v\mathrm{d}t,
\end{align*}
are increments of standard Brownian motions under $\mathbb{Q}$. Note that $\mathrm{d}W_{S,t}^\mathbb{Q}\mathrm{d}W_{v,t}^\mathbb{Q}=\rho^\mathbb{P}\mathrm{d}t$. Thus, when changing the measure, the correlation coefficient remains the same, $\rho^\mathbb{Q}=\rho^\mathbb{P}$.

---

The **new risk-neutral dynamics ($\mathbb{Q}$)** are then
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}S_t&=r S_t\mathrm{d}t+\sqrt{v_t}S_t\mathrm{d}W_{S,t}^\mathbb{Q}, \\
\mathrm{d}v_t&= \kappa^\mathbb{P} (\bar{v}^\mathbb{P}-v_t)\mathrm{d}t+\sigma^\mathbb{P}\sqrt{v_t}\mathrm{d}W_{v,t}^\mathbb{Q} -\lambda v_t\mathrm{d}t  \\
&= \left(\kappa^\mathbb{P}\bar{v}^\mathbb{P}-(\kappa^\mathbb{P}+\lambda)v_t\right)\mathrm{d}t  +\sigma^\mathbb{P}\sqrt{v_t}\mathrm{d}W_{v,t}^\mathbb{Q} \\
&= \kappa^\mathbb{Q} \left(\bar{v}^\mathbb{Q}-v_t\right)\mathrm{d}t+\sigma^\mathbb{Q}\sqrt{v_t}\mathrm{d}W_{v,t}^\mathbb{Q},
\end{align*}
which is again a square-root diffusion, where the vol-of-vol has not changed, $\sigma^\mathbb{Q}=\sigma^\mathbb{P}$. However, as in Heston (1993, Equation (27)), the speed of mean reversion and the long-term mean are now
\begin{align}
\kappa^\mathbb{Q} &= \kappa^\mathbb{P}+\lambda, \\
\bar{v}^\mathbb{Q} &= \frac{\kappa^\mathbb{P}\bar{v}^\mathbb{P}}{\kappa^\mathbb{P}+\lambda}.
\end{align}

Interestingly, $\kappa^\mathbb{P}\bar{v}^\mathbb{P}=\kappa^\mathbb{Q}\bar{v}^\mathbb{Q}$.

---

What's happening **economically**?

- The difference between the $\mathbb{P}$  and $\mathbb{Q}$ drift of $S_t$ is $(\mu^\mathbb{P}-r)S_t$. The term $\mu^\mathbb{P}-r$ is the **risk premium** (= the return a risk averse agent demands for holding a unit exposure to the shocks driving the stock price).
- The difference between the $\mathbb{P}$  and $\mathbb{Q}$ drift of $v_t$ is $\lambda v_t$. We call $\lambda$ the **[variance risk premium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_risk_premium)** (= the return a risk averse agents demands to hold a unit exposure to the variance innovations).
- The market prices of risk are **Sharpe ratios**. They divide the risk premium by the corresponding instantaneous volatilities (the $\text{d}B$-part of the SDEs).
- In **equilibrium**, $\lambda<0$ because rational agents do not like high volatility (deterioration of the investment opportunity set in an ICAPM sense, see [Campbell et al. (2018, JFE)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304405X18300503)). Empirical evidence for this is given by [Coval and Shumway (2001, JF)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/0022-1082.00352) and [Carr and Wu (2009, RFS)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/22/3/1311/1581057).
- If $\lambda<0$, then $\bar{v}^\mathbb{Q}>\bar{v}^\mathbb{P}$ and $\kappa^\mathbb{Q}<\kappa^\mathbb{P}$, i.e. variance has higher mean levels but a slower rate of mean reversion. This means the **risk-neutral distribution inflates the variance process**. This is consistent with what the stochastic discount factor should do, see [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/59789/41821). The [stochastic discount factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_discount_factor), $M_t$, is simply $M_t=e^{-rt}\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}}\bigg|_{\mathcal{F}_t}$.
- While the Radon Nikodym derivative seems to depend on the integrated variance, I'd reckon the SDF is still **[Markovian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property#Alternative_formulations)**. The stock price is Markovian too and if you write down how $S_t$ looks like, it also seems to include the integrated variance. The characteristic function $\ln(S_t)$ reveals however that the probabilistic properties only depend on the current values of the state variables, $S_t$ and $v_t$.
- Because the market is **incomplete**, there exist infinitely many risk-neutral measures. I freely chose to define the market prices of risk to be of a particular form (such that $S_t$ and $v_t$ have the same distribution under both measures, just different parameters). Other parametrisations based on minimising the error of a Delta hedge in the Heston model are possible.

---

More technical details on **Girsanov's theorem**. Suppose you want to work with independent Brownian motions. Set
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}S_t&=\mu^\mathbb{P} S_t\mathrm{d}t+\sqrt{v_t}S_t\mathrm{d}B_{1,t}^\mathbb{P}, \\
\mathrm{d}v_t&=\kappa^\mathbb{P} (\bar{v}^\mathbb{P}-v_t)\mathrm{d}t+\sigma^\mathbb{P}\sqrt{v_t}\left(\rho\mathrm{d}B_{1,t}^\mathbb{P}+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\mathrm{d}B_{2,t}^\mathbb{P}\right),
\end{align*}
where $\mathrm{d}B_{2,t}^\mathbb{P}\mathrm{d}B_{1,t}^\mathbb{P}=0$. Set, as always, $\varphi_1=\frac{\mu^\mathbb{P}-r}{\sqrt{v_t}}$ and, *importantly* let the second market price of risk, $\varphi_2$, undetermined for now (we come back to this in in the end). Then, the Girsanov theorem is concerned with independent Brownian motions only and we have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}W_{1,t}^\mathbb{Q} &= \mathrm{d}B_{1,t}^\mathbb{P} + \varphi_1\mathrm{d}t, \\
\mathrm{d}W_{2,t}^\mathbb{Q} &= \mathrm{d}B_{2,t}^\mathbb{P} + \varphi_2\mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}
Thus, by construction, we get the usual risk-neutral stock price dynamics
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}S_t&=r S_t\mathrm{d}t+\sqrt{v_t}S_t\mathrm{d}W_{1,t}^\mathbb{Q}.
\end{align*}
However, the variance process turns to
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}v_t&= \kappa^\mathbb{P} (\bar{v}^\mathbb{P}-v_t)\mathrm{d}t+\sigma^\mathbb{P}\sqrt{v_t}\left(\rho\mathrm{d}W_{1,t}^\mathbb{Q}+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\mathrm{d}W_{2,t}^\mathbb{Q}\right)\\ 
&\;\;\;\;\;\;\underbrace{-\sigma^\mathbb{P}\rho(\mu^\mathbb{P}-r)\text{d}t-\sigma^\mathbb{P}\sqrt{v_t}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\varphi_2\text{d}t}_{=\lambda(t,S_t,v_t)\text{d}t}  \\
&= \left(\kappa^\mathbb{P}(\bar{v}^\mathbb{P}-v_t)+\lambda(t,S_t,v_t)\right)\mathrm{d}t  +\sigma^\mathbb{P}\sqrt{v_t}\left(\rho\mathrm{d}W_{1,t}^\mathbb{Q}+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\mathrm{d}W_{2,t}^\mathbb{Q}\right).
\end{align*}
If you now use the same parametrisation for the variance risk premium as before, $\lambda(t,S_t,v_t)=\lambda v_t$, you recover the same risk-neutral parameters as before. Note that we did not determined $\varphi_2$ directly. We only implicitly choose a price of risk for the orthogonal Brownian motion by choosing $\lambda(t,S_t,v_t)$. Again, the main reason for this parametrisation is to keep the distribution for $v_t$ under both measures the same (although Heston provides some intuition based on the CCAPM).

Comment: Nice answer, your final sentence does make one wonder about these alternative parameterisations. Do they have practical use? If so, which? Is there enough to say about this to create a new question?

Comment: @BobJansen It's a great question. The parametrisation I chose is motivated by Heston (1993) using the CCAPM. There exists (at least) one other popular choice which chooses the variance risk premium to minimise the delta hedging error in the Heston model. That's clearly very important for traders and practical purposes (even if it's lacks some general equilibrium beauty). But I can't for the life of me remember who came up with this other variance risk premium parametrisation. Gatheral? Bergomi? Guyon? I can’t remember! :(

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. In fact, I still have a question about this. To obtain the risk-neutral measure, we can modify each SDE separately by applying Girsanov's theorem, i.e. the multi-dim Girsanov, right? What mainly confuses me is actually the correlation. I thought the multidimensional Girsanov theorem applies to uncorrelated processes. So do I understand correctly that we can apply the Girsanov theorem to correlated standard BMs and therefore do not need to write the process in terms of uncorrelated BMs?

Comment: @quantmath Good point. There are multi-dimensional Ito integral constructions that allow for non-zero correlation. But yeah, often, it's introduced for independent Brownian motions. But that's no problem. Take the Radon Nikodym derivative to be $\mathcal{E}(-\lambda_SB_{S,t}^\mathbb{P}-\lambda_OB_{O,t}^\mathbb{P})$, where $B_{O,t}$ is an orthogonal (independent) Brownian motion with its own price of risk. You can continue with the calculations and arrive at an equivalent representation for the variance risk premium.

Comment: According to [Sebastien Bossu, Advanced Equity Derivatives: Volatility and Correlation][https://www.wiley.com/en-bz/Advanced+Equity+Derivatives:+Volatility+and+Correlation-p-9781118750964] (page 52), the parameter $\lambda$ (and the corresponding risk neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}^{\lambda}$) could be determined from volatility dependent asset (Calls, Puts, Variance Swaps,..) but **this is very difficult to achieve in practice**. I would like to know whether it's because the model in the new RN measure is dificult to be used (volatility is no more CIR process) or because of other reasons?

Comment: @NN2 it's akin to why $\mu$ is so difficult to estimate. Option prices only reveal risk-neutral parameters that ``merge’’ $\mathbb{P}$ parameters and risk premiums. You can try to disentangle them using time series econometrics but that's difficult. Another way is to estimate the expected return of assets that only depend on volatility (e.g. var swaps), see Carr and Wu (2009, RFS). But estimating mean returns with high statistical accuracy is difficult too. Getting information about the $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ distribution simultaneously remains an open question in quant finance

Comment: Very very nice answer, IMHO, especially the last point: I think it is sometimes not stated *sufficiently explicitly* that (any) market-price-of-risk ansatz is usually rooted in some notion of equilibrium or in the 'wish' to stay within the distribution class.

Comment: @Kermittfrog Thank you! Sometimes, I feel people don't appreciate that the functional form of the variance risk premium is just an assumption to ease your life and that there are infinitely many other parametrisations that also yield no-arbitrage prices. It’s similar to pinning down a specific $\mathbb{Q}$ for jump models. On the other hand, we do have a lot of evidence that $\lambda<0$ and that the VRP is higher if $v_t$ is higher. So, Heston's parametrisation makes a lot of sense economically. However ultimately, CIR (1985) use the same parametrisation... again for  mathematical convenience

Comment: @quantmath Is the application of Girsanov's theorem in the Heston model any clearer to you now? Does the underlying economic argument convince you or are some of your questions left open?

Comment: @Kevin
1) How do you get the following Radon-Nikodym derivative
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}}\bigg|_{\mathcal{F}_t}= \exp\bigg(&-\int_0^t \frac{\mu^\mathbb{P}-r}{\sqrt{v_s}}\mathrm{d}B_{S,s}^\mathbb{P} -\int_0^t \frac{\lambda\sqrt{v_s}}{\sigma^\mathbb{P}}\mathrm{d}B_{v,s}^\mathbb{P} \\
&+ \int_0^t \frac{ (\mu^\mathbb{P}-r)\lambda\rho^\mathbb{P}}{\sigma^\mathbb{P}}\mathrm{d}s-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \left(\frac{(\mu^\mathbb{P}-r)^2}{v_s}+\frac{\lambda^2v_s}{(\sigma^\mathbb{P})^2} \right)\mathrm{d}s\bigg).
\end{align*}
2) Are you sure that the following is true? \b

Comment: Answers: 1) I simply used Girsanov's theorem. If you define $\varphi_t=\left(\frac{\mu-r}{\sqrt{v_t}},\frac{\lambda\sqrt{v_t}}{\xi}\right)$, you can set $\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}}\bigg|_t=\mathcal{E}\left(-\int_0^t \varphi_s\text{d}B_s^\mathbb{P}\right)$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is the [stochastic exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dol%C3%A9ans-Dade_exponential). 2) Yes, I am sure. Essentially, I can define $\varphi_2$ however I want to. In the above case, I can solve for $\varphi_2$ such that both expressions are indeed equal. $\varphi_2$ is like a free parameter.

Comment: I flagged the post such that a mod can help us to convert the posts into comments :) The wiki reference is all you need, $$\mathcal{E}\left(-\int_0^t \varphi_s\text{d}\mathbf{B}_s^\mathbb{P}\right) = \exp\left(-\int_0^t \varphi_s\text{d}\mathbf{B}_s^\mathbb{P}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \|\varphi_s\|^2\text{d}s\right).$$ All you need now is a bit on multi-dimensional Itô integrals (please look in any book sto calculus). That explanation wouldn't fit into the comments. Essentially, you integrate the two components of $\varphi$ and need to take the correlation between the Brownian motions into account.

Comment: Can you please tell me from which book you got the Radon-Nikodym derivative?

Comment: I have no book at hand. I derived it “myself” here in complete analogue to the Black-Scholes model. That said, I’m sure there are some books and papers that include this formula.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that you can apply Girsanov's theorem in this way, noting that I don't understand your (short) argument in the comments.
This is how I would proceed, which makes sense mathematically, but the economic interpretation is then a bit strange.

Let us write the SDE's a bit different, noting that it still preservers the same correlation structure
\begin{align*}
\frac{dS_t}{S_t} &= \mu dt + \sqrt{v_t} d
\left( \rho d \widehat{W}_{2,t}^\mathbb{P} +\sqrt{1- \rho^2} d\widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_{1,t} \right) \\
dv_t &= \kappa (\theta - v_t )dt + \sigma \sqrt{v_t} d\widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_2\\
\end{align*}
where $\widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_1$ and $\widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_2$ are the independent standard Brownian motions, and $\rho \in (−1,1)$
the correlation coefficient. Assuming the same market price of (volatility) risk as @Kevin or Heston and denote it by $\lambda_2$, we have
\begin{align*}
\lambda_2= \frac{\lambda \sqrt{v_t}  }{\sigma}
\end{align*}
Then, the relationships between the standard Brownian motions under the risk-neutral measure and the standard Brownian motions under the physical measure are given by
\begin{align*}
d \widehat{W}_1^{\mathbb{Q}_\lambda} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \left( \frac{\mu - r}{\sqrt{v}} - \frac{  \lambda \rho \sqrt{v_t}}{\sigma}
 \right)dt + d \widehat{W}^\mathbb{P}_1
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 d\widehat{W}^{ \mathbb{Q}_\lambda}_2 = \frac{\lambda \sqrt{v_t}  }{\sigma}dt + d \widehat{W}_2^\mathbb{P}.
\end{align*}
The two-dim market price of risk process $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \left( \frac{\mu - r}{\sqrt{v}} - \frac{  \lambda \rho \sqrt{v_t}}{\sigma}
 \right)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\lambda_2= \frac{\lambda \sqrt{v_t}  }{\sigma}
\end{align*}
and not
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 = \frac{\mu - r}{\sqrt{v_t}}
\end{align*}
Indeed, in the Black and Scholes model, the market price of risk is given by $(\mu^{BS}-r)/\sigma^{BS}$, but here I think we have to take both standard Brownians into account.

In particular, then the we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d \mathbb{P}} \bigg\vert_{\mathcal{F}_T}=
\exp \bigg( - \bigg( \int^T_0 \lambda_1(u) d \widehat{W}_{1,t}^\mathbb{P}(u) + \int^T_0 \lambda_2(u) d \widehat{W}_{2,t}^\mathbb{P}(u) \bigg) - \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \int^T_0 \lambda_1^2(u) du + \int^T_0 \lambda_2^2(u)du \bigg) \bigg)
\end{align*}

Comment: I added some more details to my answer to show how to do the calculations with independent Brownian motions. I hope that helps? The trick is to parametrise the variance risk premium at the right step during the derivation

Comment: It’s normally always defined equivalently. It’s more like that the notion changes. Normally, you can reconcile seemingly different approaches (see my edit for independent Brownian motions). I’m not quite sure what still confuses you?

Comment: @Kevin thank you for the execution.
I have read both "your" and "my" explanations of the "market price of risk" in a number of well-known books, and this market price of risk has always been defined differently, which is exactly what confuses me. Can someone perhaps address this point?

Comment: Could you please share which books define the market price of risk to be different to $\frac{\lambda v_t}{\sigma\sqrt{v_t}}=\frac{\lambda}{\sigma}\sqrt{v_t}$. Always make sure to differentiate between the “market price of risk” (a Sharpe ratio) that appears in Girsanov's theorem and the “risk premium” (difference in expected returns). These are different concepts and often confused by authors.

Comment: The above choices to parametrise the variance risk premium are very common in the literature, see [Gatheral (Equation 12)](http://web.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/ctff03/Gatheral.1.pdf) or [Carr and Wu (Equation 35)](https://engineering.nyu.edu/sites/default/files/2019-01/CarrReviewofFinStudiesMarch2009-a.pdf). Just be careful whether someoone defines the ''variance risk premium'' (proportional to $v_t$) or the ''market price of risk'' (proportional to $\sqrt{v_t}$).

Comment: @Kevin  Apart from your ideas on Girsanov's theorem, your comments are good. But I don't think it's a good idea to confuse people with your ideas. I would recommend that you re-read the books you listed on linkedin.

Comment: Thanks for finding some of my ideas helpful!:) Could you please clarify where I did an error in applying Girsanov's theorem or where I caused confusion? Perhaps I can clarify! What questions of yours are still open? Also, I never mentioned any books on linkedin?

Comment: See the following article
https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/JAMSA/Volume2006/18130.pdf
But I agree with you that many people confuse the "market price of risk" with the "risk premium", as in the above article.

Comment: That's a cool article and it really goes into the mathematical details of the measure change. I like it. When I quickly went over it, I couldn't find anything that disagrees with my answer. So, I'm still not quite sure where I caused some confusion. Let me know if you think I can improve my answer though or if you have any remaining questions

Comment: The two-dimensional Girsanov Theorem gives rise to ...
the $\rho^\mathbb{P}$ part is confusing

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the source of confusion. It all boils down to applying Girsanov's theorem correctly. Let $\varphi=(\varphi_S,\varphi_v)$ be the two market prices of risk. Then, Girsanov tells us $$A_t=\frac{\text{d}\mathbb{Q}}{\text{d}\mathbb{P}}=\mathcal{E}\left(-\int_0^t \varphi_s\text{d}\mathbf{B}_s\right),$$ where $\mathbf{B}_s$ is a vector of **correlated** Brownian motions. You can define this multiple Itô integral for uncorrelated **or** correlated Brownian motions.

Comment: Because the Heston model contains correlated Brownian motions, I think it's easiest to have correlated Brownian motions here too. You could redefine $\varphi$ and consider independent Brownian motions via the usual $\rho B_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}B_2$ argument (see the last edit to my answer), but one doesn't really gain anything from that. Instead, I think correlated Brownian motions as integrator are easier.

Comment: The definition of $A_t$ above implies $$\text{d}A_t=-\varphi_tA_t\text{d}\mathbf{B}_t.$$ You thus get 3 parts, the usual $\varphi_S\text{d}B_S$ and $\varphi_v\text{d}B_v$ as well as a correlation term, $\rho\varphi_S\varphi_v\text{d}t$ (as $\text{d}B_S\text{d}B_v=\rho\text{d}t$). By the definition of $\mathcal{E}$, the Radon-Nikodym derivative integrates these 3 components and subtracts $\frac{1}{2}$ times the integrated squared Girsanov kernels. Squaring the correlation term $\rho\varphi_S\varphi_v\text{d}t$ gives zero (order $\text{d}t^2$). Thus, it doesn't appear in the later integrals.

Comment: You see, all that's going on is applying Girsanov. Because we have two dimensions, we need to deal with correlation somehow. Either we construct an artificial set of independent Brownian motions (the edit to the answer) and blur the economic intuition where $\lambda$ comes from, or we use the 2D version of Itô integrals for correlated Brownian motions. I chose the latter because the Radon Nikodym is then nice: integrated Girsanov kernels + integrated correlations - $\frac{1}{2}$ squared Girsanov kernels. I hope that clarifies the step? Do have further questions about this (or other) steps?