# A concrete example of a stochastic discount factor

Tags: stochastic-discount

Asset pricing uses the concept of a stochastic discount factor (SDF). I have read various things about it but have not seen a concrete example. Could you give a concrete example of an SDF, e.g. one that has been estimated in an academic paper or being used by practitioners? (E.g. could it be F-distributed? Lognormally distributed? Something else?)

Comment: In the CCAPM, $M_{t,t+1}=\beta\left(\frac{C_{t+1}}{C_t}\right)^{-\gamma}$. Using data on aggregate consumption and using parameter values for $\beta$ and $\gamma$, you get realisations of the SDF. Clearly, this is not a very sophisticated model and it doesn't fit the data well, but it is a very important model and it's arguably the simplest SDF.

Comment: @Kevin, hm, let me see if I understand this. $M_{t,t+1}$ conditional on the information set $I_t$ is a random variable because $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $C_{t}$ are scalars when conditioned on $I_t$, and $C_{t+1}$ is a random variable.  Since we have a single realization of $C_{t+1}$ in the data, we get a single realization of $M_{t+1}$. That is not much of an estimate of a random variable; we would want a distribution, would we not? But perhaps we could impose some structure on the time evolution of $M$ to borrow information from across time periods, as we usually do in time series models.

Comment: You're right with everything you're saying. If we make assumptions about the distribution of consumption growth, we get the sought distribution of $M_{t,t+1}$. For example, you could assume that $C_t$ follows a geometric Brownian motion (iid consumption growth). Again, these are the simplest possible assumptions, not the most realistic ones.

Comment: @Kevin, OK, so if we employ such an assumption, can we obtain an analytical expression of $M_{t,t+1}$? What would it be?

Comment: What do you mean with "analytical expression"? The SDF is a random variable (better: a stochastic processs). I would call  $M_{t,t+1}=\beta\left(\frac{C_{t+1}}{C_t}\right)^{-\gamma}$ an analytical expression. Depending on your assumption about the distribution of consumption growth, you can then derive the probability distribution of the SDF.

Comment: @Kevin, Yes, I am after the probability distribution and after its explicit expression such as $N(5,12)$ or $t(8)$ or $F(5,2)$ (these are of course simple examples). The parameters could be explicit functions of $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest example:

- Consinder a household with utility function
  \begin{align}
  U=\mathbb{E} \int_0^\infty e^{-\beta t}\frac{C_t^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}\text{d}t
  \end{align}
- The pricing kernel (SDF) is
  \begin{align}
  \Lambda_t=e^{-\beta t}C_t^{-\gamma}
  \end{align}
- Expected stock returns are
  \begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}_t[\text{d}R_t]=r_f\text{d}t + \gamma\mathbb{E}_t\left[\frac{\text{d}C_t}{C_t}\text{d}R_t\right]
  \end{align}

---

Assume iid consumption growth: $$\frac{\text{d}C_t}{C_t}=\mu\text{d}t+\sigma\text{d}W_t$$
Then, $C_t$ is log-normally distributed and so is $C_t^{-\gamma}$ and so is $e^{-\beta t}C_t^{-\gamma}$. Put differently,
\begin{align}
\ln(\Lambda_t)&=-\beta t-\gamma\ln(C_t) \\
&=-\beta t-\gamma\left(\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t+\sigma W_t\right)
\end{align}
Thus, the probability distribution of this SDF is
\begin{align}
\ln(\Lambda_t)\sim N\left(-\beta t-\gamma\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t,\sigma^2t\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I would not derive utility from expectations, though. Utility of actual consumption would sound more reasonable. Now, is your example compatible with the CAPM? If not, would the simplest case that is in line with the CAPM be much more complicated?

Comment: $U$ is more like the objective function of the agent. We should better call it ``expected lifetime utility from consumption'' (assuming the agent never dies).

Comment: The example is totally compatible with the CAPM. In fact, this setup is a common way to derive the CAPM :)

Comment: Lovely! Thank you! (I will wait before accepting the answer in case I might get some alternative answers that are worth considering.) Also, do you have any idea about what parameter values would be compatible with empirical data?

Comment: Frankly, none. The model is known poorly describe the data. The CAPM/CCAPM just don't work empirically. We want $\gamma$ to be small (1-5), $\sigma$ is low in the data (1-2%), .. but these parameters just don't fit the data. We need better models (habits, long run risks, disasters, production, etc.) These models are great to understand concepts, run simulations, and get an idea what an SDF looks like. But the CAPM/CCAPM aren't great at explaining asset prices

Comment: It is also interesting that the support of this SDF is not only positive, so that we cannot conclude from observing this SDF that {no arbitrage opportunities + law of one price} holds, right?

Comment: The SDF is always positive and there is no arbitrage? A GBM is always strictly positive? The SDF is $\Lambda_t=e^{-\beta t}C_t^{-\gamma}>0$.

Comment: My bad, I overlooked the logarithm! Moving too quickly in unfamiliar territory :)

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Comment: @RichardHardy Perhaps these answers ([1](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/59788/41821) and [2](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/59789/41821)) also help. They are about plotting the SDF for a concrete example (Black-Scholes option pricing).

Comment: Thank you, Kevin.